# How to reload a html page when your code changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I remember watching a jquery demo by John Resig. He had a browser application that reloaded live while he was coding. I think he did not even have to save his code changes for this to happen  ( see 3:40 in the video ).

This is the video: http://vimeo.com/116991

I find this really cool and think this can be really useful and fun while you are coding.

Do you know what application he was using?
Do you know how this is done or might be done?

**Update:**
This was suggested by [Januz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236118/januz):

> You could use [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/). It reloads everytime you save a file in your project's folder.

Seems to work fine.

Comment: I think he did not even have to save his code changes for this to happen --> This is impossible without special support in the text editor he was using

Comment: " I think he did not even have to save his code changes for this to happen ( see 3:40 in the video )."

His IDE supports simply autosave :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/). It reloads everytime you save a file in your project's folder.

Answer (score 3):

Skúli - I don't have the time to watch the whole video but I think I know what you are after: the ability to refresh a web page automatically.  This can be done for any number of reasons. You might want to implement a monitor, save content, avoid timeouts, etc.

While JQuery can be useful, the overall effect is achieved using Ajax. In ASP.NET, simply place a timer on the page and a matching Ajax update panel:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" ></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the callback, you can save the state of the page (e.g. a document the user is working on) or refresh content in the update panel (there is no content shown in the panel here but I think you'll get the idea).

Comment: Regardless of the server side language he is using, the effect is always achieved using ajax :)

Comment: If you have a client side state. For example you are filling in a form I think you will always loose that state when the page is reloaded. That is why I think it is loaded when you change your code. In the video, when he is showing the page he is making it does not seem to reload. Othervise he could not show the page properly.
Can this be acchieved by only reloading if the body of the page does not have focus? I think so.

Comment: Andeas - you are right and my language was pretty awkward.  I was changing it as you commented!  Skuli - one of the reasons that Ajax is so cool is that is *won't* look like the page is reloading.  Technically, it isn't - just a part of it is.  And no, you do not lose the state of the page during an asynchronous callback.  In fact, the state of the page (in ASP.NET anyway) is sent back for use by the server.  Lastly - this has nothing to do with focus or whether the body has focus.

Comment: Could whoever clicked to downvote this answer please explain? Is there something you think I'm missing that could help Skúli solve his problem?

Comment: -1 Because Resig *certainly* would not use ASP.NET AJAX to do anything

Comment: Can you use this without having to change the server side code while the page is developed?

Comment: Josh - ummm, Ok. I wasn't aware that Resig disliked ASP.NET but, honestly, I was just trying to provide an answer that was likely to be helpful given the sheer number of people that use ASP.NET.

Skuli - you wouldn't have to change the server side code, no. Also, I think that you'd be limited to making changes within the ContentTemplate as well (the other areas would not be updated). Of course, you could just put everything of interest in the ContentTemplate area until you had all of the kinks worked out.

Comment: BTW - my assumption when you asked about changing code, though, was that you were working on the Server side. You should note that you'll lose the ASP.NET session after 6-8 refreshes if you are working on the server side or if you make a server side coding change that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a [*meta refresh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to automatically reload the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an automatic refresh-on-change tool for IE.  It's called ReloadIt, and is available at http://reloadit.codeplex.com . Free.

Not an add-on to IE, but more of an "adjunct".  It does not change the IE install, does not install a BHO or anything like that.  So very low-impact installation.

You choose a URL that you'd like to auto-reload, and specify one or more directory or file paths to monitor for changes.  Press F12 to start monitoring.

[image]

After you set it, minimize it.  Then edit your content files. When you save, the page gets reloaded.  like this:

[image]

There's no code you need to add to your solution.  It works with jQuery, or mooTools, or whatever. It works with PHP or ASPNET or python.  It works with IIS or Apache or any server technology.  The only requirement is that the page be viewed in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in this README file and it will do something near to what you want:

Actually you can do exactly refresh the page if it has no errors if you use emacs as your text editor (i.e. command emacs to save the file as soon as it has no errors)

This maybe helpful: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12459/save-buffer-at-each-modification

You can also check this script:

[Refresh-Develop](https://github.com/Ahmed1Elsawy/refresh-develop)

It works with firefox so you add the remote-control addon.

Then, use a bash script to run commands to the browser when the web directory changes.

So, in addition to this addon you need `inotify-tools` to watch the directory and `netcat` to talk to the browser when the directory changes.

Then, you can apply to any other code (maybe you use a .c file and you want to test it as soon as you save it in this case you will only need `inotify` and to modify the code from the README file)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this javascript code:

`window.setInterval("if(document.hasFocus()===false)location.reload(true);",3000);`

It works in firefox, I get a warning in IE and it doesn't work in chrome( document.hasFocus() is alway true )

Not a perfect solution, but it works, though not gracefully. The downside is that this code is in the solution itself. Using ajax that can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what he uses, but I use [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115)

Answer (score 0):

He's using a code editor with a preview window that automatically refreshes on changes to the code window. No Ajax magic!

Not sure exactly what editor he's using but I know [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) can do this, there's probably plugins for various other editors out there.