# What's the editor John Resig is using in this video?

Tags: jquery, ide, editor

The HTML in the browser reacts as he changes the code in the editor.  [What editor is he using](http://vimeo.com/116991)?

Comment: Also see [How to reload a html page when your code changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939882/how-to-reload-a-html-page-when-your-code-changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that we have no idea what video you're refering to. I'd take a stab that it could be Firebug. It allows live changes of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It's [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/).